# Text misalignment issue. Need fix. - ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android

Tags: android, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm stuck trying to print data using this library, and the alignment looks weird. Any suggestions for modifications?

I have created a issue in the repo itself [#483](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/issues/483)

Need your help!!